# Is it possible to use Tor without Tor network?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration, network-configuration

I like the feature subset Tor has from firefox and the hardened settings. I also like the IP hiding I get when using Tor for personal browsing. Sometimes however, the Tor network gets in the way when I am accessing specific sites for work. I currently switch to chrome just for those specific sites because the IP hopping is seen as a security red flag.

I would like to ask if it is possible to configure Tor browser to not use the Tor network. I actually have asked in a couple of other forums but the only response I get to my technical question is the moral debate of whether I should disable Tor network.

I appreciate any guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's *technically possible*, but it's completely useless. To do the greater dig - just use Firefox ESR and a VM

Comment: I don't see it as being useless IMO as Firefox itself is becoming more user hostile by the day.  I know there are other FF forks out there but I don't want to maintain (with extensions/addons and shortcuts ) Tor + one extra browser. I like using Tor and Tor network sometimes but not all the time.

Comment: One thing I sensed from the Tor community is that they desire anyone running Tor to participate in the network because it strengthens the network and I total get that. In fact I am more that happy to have my machine be a node in the network and serve other peoples requests but I want my own original requests to not go through Tors network sometimes

Comment: well, FfESR + TransProxy will make your day then! Feel free to drop me a line if you need some additional help - I love your idea, let's make it happen! ;)